# How to get the users internet connection speed in a web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net web application, in that I want to add a page which will do so, the page will have a button, when the end user clicks that button it will calculate the end users internet connection speed (both upload and download) and display it on the same web page.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just embed the SpeedTest.net app?

http://speedtest.net/mini.php

Answer (score 3):

To do this you'd need some javascript which would download/upload a file of known-size and time it.  Then the value of the speed would be submitted to your server, or simply displayed to the user.

This will only measure *their* connection to *your* server however.

Your best bet would be to find an app such as @SixHouse suggestion which you can then integrate into your site.